# Suppose 3 fair coins are flipped. What is the probability that all 3 are heads conditional on knowing the number of heads is odd?

Tags: probability

> Suppose 3 fair coins are flipped. What is the probability that all 3 are heads conditional on knowing the number of heads is odd?

The answer is $1/4$ and I don't understand how.

Using $P(A\mid B)=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}$

The probability of having 3 heads is $\frac{1}{8}$, the probability of having an odd number of heads is $\frac{1}{2}$

So $P(A\mid B)=\frac{(1/8)(1/2)}{(1/2)}=1/8$ What am I not understanding?

Comment: Why do you have $1/2$ in the numerator?

Comment: multiplying the probabilities together to get the probability of both being true?

Comment: Those events aren’t independent. Can you think of a way to get three heads without having an odd number of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

$Pr(A\cap B) = Pr(A)\times Pr(B)$ is true if *and only if* $A$ and $B$ are independent events.  These events certainly are *not* independent and so the above would be an inequality, not an equality.

Instead, recognize that "All three are heads" directly implies that "The number of heads is odd"

> And so $A\subseteq B$ in this specific situation.

$~$

> And so $Pr(A\cap B)=Pr(A)$ in this specific situation.